'Form' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its return type 'ReactNode' is not a valid JSX element
I'm encountering an issue with my Next.js application written in TypeScript after updating react-bootstrap. Following the update, I receive the following error when trying to use the Form component from react-bootstrap:
react-bootstrap: ^2.10.3
@types/react-bootstrap: ^0.32.36
react: ^18.2.0
react-dom: ^18.2.0
typescript: 5.0.2
@types/react: ^18.2.30
@types/react-dom: ^18.2.14

Here is the content of my tsconfig.json:
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "jsx": "react-jsx",
        "incremental": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["./*"]
        }
    },
    "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "types/**/*.d.ts"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

Steps I Have Already Tried:
Verified that all dependencies are updated and compatible.
Removed and reinstalled node_modules and package-lock.json.
Checked the changelog of react-bootstrap for any breaking changes.
Has anyone faced a similar issue after updating react-bootstrap? Any suggestions on how to resolve this type error with Form in a JSX component?
My React Component
Here is the code of the component that is causing the issue
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Form, Button, Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
import PromotersTable from './PromotersTable';
import usePromoterContract from '../customHooks/usePromoterManagement';
import { PromoterModel } from '../types';

const AddPromoterForm: React.FC = () => {
    const { addPromoter, getPromoters } = usePromoterContract();
    const [promoterAddress, setPromoterAddress] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(true);
    const [promoters, setPromoters] = useState<PromoterModel[]>([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchPromoters = async () => {
            try {
                const result = await getPromoters();
                const promotersData: PromoterModel[] = result.map((item: any) => ({
                    promoterAddress: item.promoterAddress,
                    isActive: item.isActive,
                    percentage: item.percentage,
                    profit: item.profit,
                    referralCode: item.referralCode,
                }));
                setPromoters(promotersData);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching promoters:', error);
            }
        };

        fetchPromoters();
    }, [getPromoters]);

    const validateEmail = (email: string): boolean => {
        const re = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
        return re.test(email);
    };

    const handleAddPromoter = async (event: React.FormEvent) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        if (!validateEmail(email)) {
            Swal.fire({ title: 'Invalid Email!', icon: 'error' });
            return;
        }

        setLoading(true);
        try {
            console.log('handleAddPromoter - addPromoter - start');
            await addPromoter(promoterAddress, email);
            resetForm();
            console.log('handleAddPromoter - addPromoter - end');
        } catch (error: any) {
            console.log(' ~ handleAddPromoter ~ error:', error);
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    };

    const resetForm = () => {
        setPromoterAddress('');
        setEmail('');
        setIsActive(true);
    };

    return (
        <Container>
            <h2>Create Promoter</h2>
            <Form onSubmit={handleAddPromoter}>
                <Form.Group controlId="formPromoterAddress">
                    <Form.Label>Promoter Address</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter promoter's address"
                        value={promoterAddress}
                        onChange={e => setPromoterAddress(e.target.value)}
                        required
                    />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group controlId="formEmail">
                    <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type="email"
                        placeholder="Enter promoter's email"
                        value={email}
                        onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                        required
                    />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group controlId="formIsActive">
                    <Form.Check
                        type="checkbox"
                        label="Active"
                        checked={isActive}
                        onChange={e => setIsActive(e.target.checked)}
                    />
                </Form.Group>
                <div className="my-4 mx-auto text-center col-12">
                    <Button variant="primary" type="submit" size="sm" disabled={loading} className="w-100">
                        {loading ? 'Loading...' : 'Add Promoter'}
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </Form>
            <div className="h-50 overflow-y-auto">
                <PromotersTable promoters={promoters} />
            </div>
        </Container>
    );
};

export default AddPromoterForm;


Check if this helps ReactNode is not a JSX element

I had to revert to typescript 5.4.5 (new 5.5.2 breaks)
